# iPad - iOS 4.2 Force a app to shut down

Tags: ipad, ios4

We are testing our app on an iPad with 4.2 on it.

How do we force the app to stop. We are testing the initial load section of code and of course that only fires when the app starts up.

Reminds me of a similar issue on our Android apps....

Comment: You might want to disable multi-tasking on your app temporarily for a faster workflow. You can explicitly opt out of the background execution model by adding the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key to your application’s Info.plist file and setting its value to YES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-click the home button, hold your finger down on the app, and then tap the red minus sign.

Comment: I think you might mean the home button.